# Why can't get script to proceed to next page and stop reload after checkout click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, shopify

I am creating a script which takes a minimum of 16 characters in Address field and exactly 10 in the Phone field in Shopify checkout page.

My issue's - The entire page refresh's/load's after click & Even after validating all the fields i cant proceed to next page.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#checkout_shipping_address_address1').attr("minlength",16);
    $('#checkout_shipping_address_address1').attr("name",'addressOne');
    $('#checkout_shipping_address_address1').attr("maxlength",200);
    $('#checkout_shipping_address_address1').attr("required",'required');
    $("form.edit_checkout.animate-floating-labels").validate(
      {
        messages: {
          checkout_shipping_address_phone: "Please enter 10 digit phone number",
          addressOne: "Enter an address of minimum 16 characters",
        }
      }
    );
  });
</script>


<script>
  (function($) { 
    window.PhoneNumberInputFormatter=function(){return true;};
    $(document).on('page:load page:change', function() {
      if (Shopify.Checkout.step === 'contact_information') {
        var $phoneField = $('[name="checkout[shipping_address][phone]"]:not([tabindex="-1"])');
            phoneFormatValidated = true;
        $phoneField.removeAttr('data-phone-formatter data-phone-formatter-country-select');
        $phoneField.attr('maxlength', 10);
        $phoneField.attr('minlength', 10);
        $phoneField.attr('required', 'required');
        $phoneField.attr('name', 'checkout_shipping_address_phone');
        $phoneField.keypress(function(event){
      if (event.which != 48 && (event.which < 47 || event.which > 59))
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ((event.which == 46) && ($(this).indexOf('.') != -1)) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
        function phoneNumberValidation() {
          phoneFormatValidated = true;
          var phoneFieldVal = $phoneField.val();
        }
        if ($phoneField.val() != "") { phoneNumberValidation() };
        $phoneField.on('blur', phoneNumberValidation);
        $('[data-step] form [type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          phoneNumberValidation();
          if (phoneFormatValidated) {
            $('[data-step] form').trigger('submit');
          }
        });
        $('[data-step] form').on('keypress', function(e) {           
          if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('[data-step] form [type="submit"]').trigger('click');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  })
  (Checkout.$);
</script>
```

P.S - I am new to JS/JQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: Is validation works well? and Shopify plus on your subscription or make changes thought scripts section from backend?

Comment: Yes it works well, and i have entered this script into checkout.liquid within shopify plus.